# How to make an interface made in C++ Builder responsive during a heavy computation?

Tags: delphi, user-interface, c++builder

I have a piece of software written in C++ Builder 6 (yes, I know that it's terribly outdated and I'm not going to rewrite it). It does heavy number crunching which takes a few minutes to complete. I want interface to be responsive during these computations. I remember there was an extremely simple solution for this problem in Delphi - calling a special method of form/app, but I can't remember what was it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Best solution is to put the calc in a separate thread. ProcessMessages will likely lead to pain.

Comment: Yeah, but rewriting code to work in a separate thread will likely lead to pain too. Hacky solutions sometimes are acceptable.

Comment: Andrew: faced with a similar situation (more pressing because my computations could last hours) I shifted my computations to a separate thread, and the speedup was incredible!  The OS moved my compute thread to another core (not the one being used by the foreground process) and computations went far, far faster.  Worth the small investment in refactoring.

Comment: @Andrew It depends on how messy the code is to begin with. But, usually it's not so much pain to move code into a separate thread. I wrote a related answer on another thread a couple of days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11047262/446105. If you're not familiar with the TThread object, you may get some help from it (it's Delphi code, but I guess the TThread object works the same way in C++ Builder).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Application.ProcessMessages();` but it has [dark side](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/delphi-processmessages-dark-side.htm).

Answer (score 3):

In Delphi, that's `Application.Processmessages()`.  Be aware thought that calling that methode has some side effects, like described [here](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/delphi-processmessages-dark-side.htm).

Answer (score 3):

You know you have to do it, Andrew. You know you have to do the number crunching in a separate thread. Now go and implement it.

Answer (score 2):

You could modify the program to do all of the number crunching in a background thread which will not lock up your GUI. More complicated than the other answers here, but it is an option open to you.